# How to left join and select by condition max, then choose another field?

Tags: sql, hana

**DB: SAP HANA**

How to left join and select by condition max, then choose another field ?

A

| user | no | qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 20 |
| A | 11 | 30 |
| B | 12 | 40 |
| B | 13 | 10 |

B

| id | user |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |

Expected result

| id | user | no |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 11 |
| 2 | B | 12 |

Is there a sql like

```sql
select B.id, B.user, MAX(qty).NO
from B
left join A
on A.user = B.user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following to achieve this:

```sql
SELECT
    B.id,
    B.user,
    C.max_qty_no
FROM
    B
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        A.user,
        CASE
            WHEN A.qty = (
              MAX(A.qty) OVER (PARTITION BY A.user)
            ) THEN A.no
        END as max_qty_no
    FROM
        A
) C ON C.user = B.user AND
       C.max_qty_no IS NOT NULL;
```

or

```sql
SELECT
    B.id,
    B.user,
    C.max_qty_no
FROM
    B
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        A.user,
        REPLACE(
            MAX(CONCAT(A.qty,'-',A.no)),
            MAX(CONCAT(A.qty,'-')),''
                        
        ) as max_qty_no
    FROM
        A
    GROUP BY 
       A.user
) C ON C.user = B.user;
```

Let me know if this works for you[.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vFWCiyv5jG3tktJm8gXwjg/1)